# Intent image share-file format not supported

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I'm unable to share the image on social media
when I clicked on the share button.
It showed the `Toast`

> File format not supported

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         upload = uploads.get(position);

       holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
       final String imageUrl=upload.getUrl();


        Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
        
        final Uri imageUri=Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/memories-project.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FnCfBZThQykf3Ur9oNzHyEHS1DEp2%2F45007?alt=media&token=9ae17594-13ff-40f6-98f9-aff80ab2fdf4");
        holder.shareImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context,imageUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");

                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
           
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                try {
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image File"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I stored images to `firebase`.
Now I get the link from firebase and parse into URI but I don't know why this is showing.

> I hardcoded the URL just for testing purposes.

For WhatsApp:

> File Format not supported

For Instagram:

> Image Unable to load

For Facebook :

> Showed nothing means no Toast or anything(Just Showed the status bar)

For Messenger:

> Not opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM), `EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to point to "A `content:` URI holding a stream of data associated with the `Intent`, used with `ACTION_SEND` to supply the data being sent."

You are supplying an `https` `Uri`, and other apps will not be expecting it. Not every possible app that supports `ACTION_SEND` will have the `INTERNET` permission, anyway.

If you want to share some content, typically it needs to be local on the device and shared via a `FileProvider` or some other form of `ContentProvider`. Prior to Android 7.0, a `file` scheme pointing to a file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) often works as well.