# Command of FFMPEG to make a video from Image(JPEG) + Audio(.mp3) & Share video in Whatsapp

Tags: android, video, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video .mp4 file from .mp3 audio & .jpeg image.

I am able to create a video and able to play it in video players on Android devices.

**But after creation of file when I tried to share that video in WhatsApp, at that time it shows a message "The file format not supported".**

I am using below FFMPEG command:

```
"-loop 1 -r 1 -i " + imageFilePath + " -i " + audioFilePath + " -c:v libx264 -crf 27 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -shortest " + pathOutputVideo(sectionName);
```

And for sharing video, I am using code listed below:

```
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ShareQuestionAudioActivity.this, new String[]{FfmpegController.pathOutputVideo(qModel.getSectionName().toUpperCase().replaceAll(" ", "_"))},
                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.setType("video/*");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(FfmpegController.pathOutputVideo(qModel.getSectionName().toUpperCase().replaceAll(" ", "_"))));
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Question"));
                    }
                });
```

I found [here](https://www.quora.com/Which-video-formats-does-WhatsApp-support) that I need to use H.264 + AAC. **But I'm still not able to share video with supported file format**.

Comment: what you used to convert images to Video?

Comment: I am using FFMPEG only to **combine Image + Audio to get Video [.mp4] output.** @AndroidUser

Comment: @NeelMevada can you share the mp4 file you created?

Comment: @NeelMevada another question, why didn't you set shareIntent.setType("video/mp4"); for mp4 file?

Comment: its also a possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744296/intent-image-share-file-format-not-supported)

Comment: @incBrain I tried with video/mp4 but same issue occures. 

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744296/intent-image-share-file-format-not-supported) >> This post is related to Image and I am able to share image to whatsapp. I am getting an issue in sending Videos Only.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: @NeelMevada ok so if you are able to do it with the image using similar approach its good. I can try to take a deeper look at the mp4 file you created, maybe I can figure something out. One thing which I can see from your ffmpeg options is -c:a copy while you are using .mp3. this will not create AAC audio. Try to remove -c:a copy (ffmpeg should do aac by default, if not specify aac audio codec in the options)

Comment: @incBrain Thank you for your support. This is been resolved with using AAC audio codec in this command.
now i am using -c:a aac and it runs well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments the problem occurs due to the audio not to be encoded using AAC codec since `-c:a copy` was used on `mp3` audio files.

The solution to this is to tell `ffmpeg` to re-encode audio stream to AAC using `-c:a aac`.
More examples on how to encode AAC can also be found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).